# html to canvas does not screenshot the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

So, I got this code to screenshot the page when I click a square:

```
$("#empty").click(function(){

        html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            });
        })
```

but the screen I got does not include the background (I set an image as background). The background in the screenshot is white, like it wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is being loaded from a different origin (not from the same site as where your code runs), due to security reasons, that image by default won't be rendered into the canvas. You can try adding `{ allowTaint: true }` to the option to see if it helps in your case.

```
html2canvas(document.body, { allowTaint: true }).then(function(canvas) {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

> allowTaint | false | Whether to allow cross-origin images to taint the canvas

You can find other configurations here: [html2canvas configuration - github](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/9a6e57aa00e422bf22482dbf56de33d5aada3633/docs/configuration.md)

Comment: you mean in the css of the img? or where?

Comment: In your html2canvas function: `html2canvas(document.body, { allowTaint: true })`

Comment: I still has the same problem. Just found out that if I click 2 times in a row I got two images:

The first same as always
The second is the image of the web with the background, but it's height is lager than the page itself.

Comment: Idk if this helps, but the web is not online. I'm woriking on it and the img is loaded from the same folder of the html folder.